# Procedure para aumentar data de devolução

Tags: sql, oracle, funções, procedure

Tenho a seguinte tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE Emprestimo (
 id int PRIMARY KEY,
 dataRetirada date DEFAULT current_date,
 dataPrevistaDevolucao date DEFAULT current_date + 7,
 dataDevolucao date,
 codigoUsuario int,
 codigoExemplar int,
  FOREIGN KEY(CodigoUsuario) REFERENCES Usuario (CodigoUsuario),
  FOREIGN KEY(CodigoExemplar) REFERENCES Exemplares (CodigoExemplar)
);
```

E preciso a partir desta tabela fazer uma procedure que estenda em 5 dias o prazo de devolução (sem passar do máximo de dias do mês) passando uma ID pro procedure, a principio seria bom utilizar a procedure para chamar uma function porém foi me passado muito pouco sobre procedure;

Obs: Estou desenvolvendo dentro do Oracle SQL developer

O que eu consegui até agora:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P_Emprestimo (idE INT)IS BEGIN update Emprestimo set dataPrevistaDevolucao = dataPrevistaDevoluçao + 7 where id = idE; END;
```

E ele me retorna:

> Erro(3,2): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
>   Erro(4,30): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "DATAPREVISTADEVOLUÇAO": identificador
>   inválido

Comment: O erro é estranho. Parece que ele não encontra a coluna da tabela. Tens a certeza que a tabela está criada? Está no schema certo?

Comment: Sim esta criada, mas agora ela funcionou, eu tive que colocar o dataPrevistaDevolucao tudo em maiusculo no SET e só ai a procedure foi compilada, achei estranho ela compilar somente com o set em maisculo;
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P_Emprestimo (idE INT)IS
BEGIN
 update Emprestimo
 set DATAPREVISTADEVOLUCAO = DATAPREVISTADEVOLUCAO + 7
 where id = idE;
END;

 EXEC P_Emprestimo (1);
select * from emprestimo

Answer (score -1):

Oq eu consegui até agora:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P_Emprestimo (idE INT)IS
BEGIN
 update Emprestimo
 set dataPrevistaDevolucao = dataPrevistaDevoluçao + 7
 where id = idE;
END;
```

Oq ele me retorna:

> ```
> Erro(3,2): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
> Erro(4,30): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "DATAPREVISTADEVOLUÇAO": identificador inválido
> ```